# Annotation near maximum characters causes Oops Something Bad Happened

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, 500-server-error, annotations

When annotating a user account we have a total of 300 characters that we can use, however if the message contains carriage returns it fails each time with the *Oops Something Bad Happened*, even if there are characters remaining on the counter.

**Steps to reproduce issue:**

Write a long annotation message with carriage returns for example:

```
voting ring 
http://stackoverflow.com/users/xxxxxxx/userxxxxxxx, 
http://stackoverflow.com/users/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx, 
http://stackoverflow.com/users/xxxxxxx/userxxxxxxx, 
http://stackoverflow.com/users/xxxxxxx/xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx, 
http://stackoverflow.com/users/xxxxxxx/userxxxxxxx same IP diff email
```

The counter shows that there is 1 character left for the message.  Upon hitting submit you will be directed to the *Oops something bad happened error page*.

However if you write the same message without the carriage returns the message is accepted without any issues.

Can this be fixed to strip the carriage returns or not throw an error when posting an annotation with it?

Comment: FWIW, you could just remove the username (the part after `/users/xxx/`) and the links would still work.

Comment: @Doorknob I know that but it is much easier to copy and paste the full link - less room for error - at least for me.

Comment: On that topic, the maximum length could use being raised, precisely for this kind of situation (multiple links to relevant users or posts to illustrate a problematic pattern).

Comment: Is this still an issue today?

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog I can't reproduce it.